# Можно ли сортировать результат по условию?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
    SELECT p.product_id,
  (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id)
    AS rating
FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN product_tag pt ON (p.product_id = pt.product_id)
WHERE pd.language_id = '2'
      AND p.status = '1'
      AND p.date_available <= NOW()
      AND p2s.store_id = '0'
      AND ( LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%24%' OR  LCASE(pt.tag) LIKE '%24%' AND pt.language_id = '2')  or  pd.product_id = '24'
LIMIT 0,15
```

Можно ли вывести в первую очередь строку найденную по условию `pd.product_id = '24'` если она есть?

Comment: `order by if(pd.product_id = 24, 0, 1)`

Comment: Спасибо, работает так